# How to run integration test inside a docker container in drone pipeline

Tags: drone.io

I have a docker image built up for mongodb test. You can be found from `zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat`. When start a docker container from this image, it will create a few mongodb instances which will take a few minutes to startup. Now I want to run my integration test cases inside this container by drone CI. Below is my .drone.yml file:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: node:latest
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm test
      - npm run eslint
  integration:
    image: zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm run integration
```

There are two steps in this pipeline, the first is to run unit test in a nodejs project. The second one `integration` is used to run integration test cases in the mongodb docker image.

when I run `drone exec` it will get an error `failed to connect to mongo instance`. I think that because the mongodb instance needs a few minutes to startup. The commands `npm install` and `npm run integration` should be run after the mongodb instance launched. How can I delay the build commands?

**EDIT1**

The image `zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat` has mongodb environment. It will create a few mongodb instances. I can run this command `docker run -d zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat` to launch this container after that I can attach to this container to see the mongodb instances. I am not sure how drone launch the docker container.

Comment: Is this the full yaml example? Where is the mongodb docker image being started? have you taken a look at http://readme.drone.io/usage/services-guide/ ?

Comment: Yes it is the full yaml file. The mongodb docker is built in this image `zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat`.

Comment: services such as mongodb should be declared in the services section. See http://readme.drone.io/usage/services-guide for examples. It is not considered best practice to start services in the pipeline.

Comment: aside from this not being the recommended approach for using drone, you should also know that the `commands` section override the default entrypoint. This means any entrypoint or command you defined in the `zhaoyi0113/mongo-uat` Dockerfile will not execute (source http://readme.drone.io/usage/getting-started/#commands)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended approach to integration testing is to place your service containers in the service section of the Yaml [1][2]

Therefore in order to start a Mongo service container I would create the below Yaml file. The Mongo service will start on the default port at 127.0.0.1 and be accessible from your pipeline containers.

```
pipeline:
  test:
    image: node
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm run test
  integration:
    image: node
    commands:
      - npm run integration

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.0
```

This is the recommended approach for testing services like MySQL, Postgres, Mongo and more.

[1] http://readme.drone.io/usage/getting-started/#services
[2] http://readme.drone.io/usage/services-guide/

Answer (score 0):

As a short addendum to Brads answer: While the mongo service will run on 127.0.0.1 on the drone host machine - it will not be possible to reach the service from this IP **within** the node app. To access the service you would reference its service name (here: mongo).